# App Crashes after chaning Theme to "NoActionBar"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hi I have to change my App theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar". But after I changed it, the app crashes. I could not find out where the problem is :/

My goal is to expand my Navigation Drawer over the toolbar. But for that, I need the "NoActionBar" function. I hope someone can help me out.
Thanks forwards!

That is the error code from the debugger:

```
12-23 11:04:28.292 1410-1421/? E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK: Failed to apply optimization for resource: 4 level: 0
```

That is my styles.xml code:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:listDivider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: post your error log also

Comment: @Tej Where I can read it out? Sry but Iam new on Android Studio :(

Comment: there is a Logcat menu at the bottom of android studio . Open it , you will find your error there

Comment: They are written when you Run or debug the app! There are Tabs at the Bottom! @SinanKara

Comment: I updated my Question and added the error code

Comment: Check this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478925/why-is-apptheme-noactionbar-not-working

Comment: Post your code in your question

Comment: My code was too long for the question. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Focusing on your style

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

This theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` means you are telling android not to take default `ActionBar`

and than Later you are calling `ActionBar` 
in your `MainAcitvity` which is the cause for your crash.

Instead use `Toolbar` and set as `ActionBar` :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Also I think you are using lolipop so add this in your styles.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in your manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".activity.YourActivity"
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
```

Comment: I tried it out, but than it crashed again with that error code : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: And this is not the error log you should post. Post whole exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494458/how-to-fix-java-lang-classcastexception-android see this link and learn how to post error log

Comment: Sry iam new on android studio :/  But I cant post the error code because its too long

Comment: I wrote an answer where I have put in the main activity and the error code

Comment: No, Sadly it did not

Comment: Still crashing ?

Comment: Jap, I try to fix it since thursday xD But I still couldn't find the problem :/

Answer (score 3):

1.Go to MainActivity.java file
2.Comment this line of code
`//NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);`
3.crash should be fixed

**Reason why**
You're using "Bottom Navigation Activity", the reason it crashing because java tries to get the object from Actionbar, When the Actionbar is disabled it returns null cause we don't have an action bar, To fix this you need to comment or remove code out
if you go to MainActivity.java (in case you're using java) you will see this code on line 26 and it tries to get set up the action bar. we can comment the code out and it should work fine.

Sorry for my bad English.

`NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);`

Comment: It solves the crash problem but the Bottom Navigation doesn't work. Any solutions for making it work with the navigation without the `ActionBar`?

Comment: NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavView, navController);

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy, there are two ways to change your actionBar:

1. You could change under `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

which will cause crash.

2. You could also change it under `src/main/res/values/themes.xml`:

If you change it such as:

```
<style name="Theme.MyQuizApp"
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

It should solve the problem.