# How to remove The title bar in android studio

Tags: java, android, app-store

My program  crashed when i put a android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

How can I remove the title without crash the program and without removing the action bar?
I am using a navigation with AppBarConfiguration

Notes : this doesnt work
true

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the logcat output of the error that comes with the crash. By any chance would this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951491/app-crashes-after-chaning-theme-to-noactionbar

Answer (score 0):

check your style file and make sure you use the same theme and upload an ERROR screenshot to fast and right answer

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

`@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`

or

this:
`<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`  
in AndroidManifest.xml

and you can check here if this doesn't work:
[How to hide the title bar for an Activity in XML with existing custom theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)